# Sort order by multiple fields Magento Custom collection

Tags: mysql, magento, sql-order-by, magento-1.9

here is my table structure:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | event_date          |
+----+---------------------+
| 12 | 2017-07-03 01:12:00 |
| 42 | 2017-07-04 18:13:00 |
| 52 | 2017-07-22 23:52:00 |
| 62 | 2017-10-20 23:55:00 |
+----+---------------------+
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status     | tinyint(2)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| content    | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| event_date | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to get latest two records with date order as ascending.

Following is the code I am using :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("blogpromo/blogpromo")->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', 0)
        ->setOrder('id', 'DESC')
        ->setOrder('event_date', 'ASC')
        ->setPageSize(2);
```

It is giving records using ID. I want to sort by using both fields. 
Although, when I tried to sort using only date, it worked fine.

Comment: It will be helpful if anyone provide raq mysql query. I am using following but it not working too:

`SELECT id,event_date FROM blog_promo ORDER BY event_date ASC, id DESC LIMIT 2;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `addAttributeToSort()`

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("blogpromo/blogpromo")->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', 0)
    ->addAttributeToSort('id', 'DESC')
    ->addAttributeToSort('event_date', 'ASC')
    ->setPageSize(2);
```

Comment: I am not using eav. As addAttributeToSort is used for eav rather than for  flat model.